# Import txt file from computer to windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

to finish my app, I need something to load a txt file from computer to Windows phone 8.1 when USB is connected, in c# windows mobile app.
I found nothing related to this, and can't develop any code.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you want it to be a part of application, or one-time thing related to debugging? For latter, I recomend Windows Phone Power Tools. For first, then it is quite a problem, and without using OneDrive it is really hard.

Comment: i want it to be part of the app.
It should be with a button. and when the device is plugged to computer i press the button and it import and read the txt file.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible without building some kind of service on PC. You may be interested in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx#roaming_app_data or OneDrive, which is nice workaround, but not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/), a very handy tool. Just select the device -> select the app -> upload your file into the Isolated Storage.

[image]

Comment: This will work only on developer's phone, not on the app downloaded from Store.

Comment: That's absolutely correct, but for this case should fine as the question refers to the development stage.